# Grouping SQL query by userid

Tags: php, mysql

I have a `orders` table with the following columns:

```
-userid
-orderid (primary key)
-date
-name
-qty
```

So I would like to display in tables in a summary page all orders and group them under each userid. So it would be like

```
Userid: 0001
| Orderid | Name   | QTY |
|  1001   | Item A | 10  |
|  1002   | Item B | 5   |

Userid: 0003
| Orderid | Name   | QTY |
|  1003   | Item C | 6   |
|  1004   | Item C | 7   |
```

So far I've experimented and got:

1. display in a single table all the items ordered by userid
2. with a GROUP BY userid, I've managed to create as many tables as there are different userid

But I can't seem to combine the two into the desired results and would really appreciate some advice on what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance and I hope my explanation made sense!

Comment: the `GROUP BY` clause is not need here. You will only execute `SELECT UserID, Orderid, Name, QTY FROM orders` and the result of the query will then be formatted on application level.

Comment: But this gives me the list of orders for all userid. I would like to group each row under a userid and display them in tables. Like instead of having 4 rows of:
`0001 - 1001 - Item A - 10`
`0001 - 1002 - Item B - 5`
`0003 - 1003 - Item C - 6`
`0003 - 1004 - Item C - 7`

I would like to group them under 2 tables like userid 0001 has 2 items, userid 0003 has 2 items, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will need to do this in PHP

Query with

```
select * from orders order by userid, orderid
```

In PHP something like this psudo code

```
$this_user_id=0;

for (each order line)
{
get fields from db result;
if ($this_user_id!=$userid)
{
$this_user_id=$orderid// save change of userid flag
print user heading;
}

print order lines;
}
```

Comment: thanks! I don't really understand how this works but I'm experimenting with what you have given me :)

Comment: each row of the mysql result set will contain the userid, orderid, item & qty. so just loop through this as normal in the for loop, but only printing orderid, item & qty for each result row. But, before you do that, see if you have found a new userid and is so print the user heading, $this_user_id will flag a change in userid and it's why it's set to zero before the loop

Comment: Oh! this makes so much sense now thanks, I'll give it a whirl and let you know how ti goes! Much appreciate!